# Run Jquery slideDown only once per session

Tags: javascript, jquery

The function below shows a notification toolbar when the user visits a page. The toolbar slides down from the top of the window, pushing down the page content.

This is OK, but the effect becomes annoying when visiting more pages. What I am trying to accomplish: slide down the notification toolbar only the first time the user interacts with the site. After the notification is first displayed, if the user refreshes the page or visits other site pages, the notification toolbar is shown instantly, with no slide down effect.

I should probably use SessionStorage for this, just don't exactly how.

```
$(function(){
$('#notification_toolbar').slideDown();
});
```

Comment: are you setting any session using PHP or any server-side language?

Comment: I am not using PHP. I can use only use javascript / Jquery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you've already mentioned `sessionStorage`, it's pretty easy to use it to save a flag that tells you if the slideDown already happened or not. Then you can use that flag to make sure it doesn't happen again.

Inside you slide down code:

```
// perform the slide down only if the slide down flag wasn't set
if(sessionStorage.getItem('hasSlideDown') !== 'yes') {  // check if slide down flag was set
    sessionStorage.setItem('hasSlideDown', 'yes');      // set the slide down flag
    $('#notification_toolbar').slideDown();             // perform the slide down
}
```

How [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) works:

> A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores. Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated, which differs from how session cookies work.

Comment: why the empty `var state = ;`

Comment: Using your script the notification toolbar is never shown after the first slide down. I need to show it instantly (with no slide down effect) after the first interaction.

Comment: Well that's probably because your toolbar is hidden by default to make your slideDown work. Is this correct? You can solve this by adding an `else { $('#notification_toolbar').css('visibility', 'visible'); }` to the above `if` statement

Comment: Yes, the slidedown container is set to display:none using CSS.

Comment: Well... how do I fix this? :)

Comment: Ok, then add this else block: `else { $('#notification_toolbar').css('display', 'block'); }` to update the display accordingly.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to persist information that slide animation was already performed, and in your code you need to put conditional like

```
if (skipAnimation) {
  # put your code to show toolbar without slide animation here
}
```

You can achive that in many ways: using url querystring (append ?skipAnimation=true to your address) or by using your session storage. Querystring would be easiest, as you can easily read it with jquery. Session storage would give your users better experience.